# getting error in header page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i will getting error this

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function gdlr_print_header_social() in /home2/u9447441/public_html/wp-content/themes/clevercourse-v1-27/header.php on line 63
```

and on line 63 the code is this

```
            <?php gdlr_print_header_social(); ?>
```

and this is full page code of hearder.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie ie7 ltie8 ltie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie ie8 ltie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0" />
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>  <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

    <?php 
        global $theme_option, $gdlr_post_option;
        if( !empty($gdlr_post_option) ){ $gdlr_post_option = json_decode($gdlr_post_option, true); }

        wp_head(); 
    ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php
    $body_wrapper = '';
    if($theme_option['enable-boxed-style'] == 'boxed-style'){
        $body_wrapper  = 'gdlr-boxed-style';
        if( !empty($theme_option['boxed-background-image']) && is_numeric($theme_option['boxed-background-image']) ){
            $alt_text = get_post_meta($theme_option['boxed-background-image'] , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);  
            $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($theme_option['boxed-background-image'], 'full');
            echo '<img class="gdlr-full-boxed-background" src="' . $image_src[0] . '" alt="' . $alt_text . '" />';
        }else if( !empty($theme_option['boxed-background-image']) ){
            echo '<img class="gdlr-full-boxed-background" src="' . $theme_option['boxed-background-image'] . '" />';
        }
    }

    $body_wrapper .= ($theme_option['enable-float-menu'] != 'disable')? ' float-menu': '';
?>
<div class="body-wrapper <?php echo $body_wrapper; ?>" data-home="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" >
    <?php 
        // page style
        if( empty($gdlr_post_option) || empty($gdlr_post_option['page-style']) ||
              $gdlr_post_option['page-style'] == 'normal' || 
              $gdlr_post_option['page-style'] == 'no-footer'){ 
    ?>
    <header class="gdlr-header-wrapper">
        <!-- top navigation -->
<img src="http://google.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/9.png" style="display:block; margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto; margin-top:10px;"/> 
<hr />
        <?php if( empty($theme_option['enable-top-bar']) || $theme_option['enable-top-bar'] == 'enable' ){ ?>
        <div class="top-navigation-wrapper">
            <div class="top-navigation-container container">
                <div class="top-navigation-left">   
                    <div class="top-navigation-left-text">
                    <?php 
                        if( !empty($theme_option['top-bar-right-text']) ) 
                            echo gdlr_text_filter($theme_option['top-bar-right-text']); 
                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="top-navigation-right">
                    <div class="top-social-wrapper">
                    <?php gdlr_print_header_social(); ?>
<div style="display: inline-block; *display: inline;  *zoom:1; font-size:12px;">
<img src="http://google.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/6.png" />  info@google.com 
</div>
                 </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
<br />
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <!-- logo -->
        <div class="gdlr-header-inner">
            <div class="gdlr-header-container container">
                <!-- logo -->
                <div class="gdlr-logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" >
                        <?php 
                            if(empty($theme_option['logo-id'])){ 
                                echo gdlr_get_image(GDLR_PATH . '/images/logo.png');
                            }else{
                                echo gdlr_get_image($theme_option['logo-id']);
                            }
                        ?>                      
                    </a>
                    <?php
                        // mobile navigation
                        if( class_exists('gdlr_dlmenu_walker') && has_nav_menu('main_menu') &&
                            ( empty($theme_option['enable-responsive-mode']) || $theme_option['enable-responsive-mode'] == 'enable' ) ){
                            echo '<div class="gdlr-responsive-navigation dl-menuwrapper" id="gdlr-responsive-navigation" >';
                            echo '<button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>';
                            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location'=>'main_menu', 
                                'container'=> '', 
                                'menu_class'=> 'dl-menu gdlr-main-mobile-menu',
                                'walker'=> new gdlr_dlmenu_walker() 
                            ) );                        
                            echo '</div>';
                        }                       
                    ?>                      
                </div>

                <!-- navigation -->
                <?php get_template_part( 'header', 'nav' ); ?>  

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="gdlr-header-substitute" ></div>
    <div class="gdlr-nav-search-form" id="gdlr-nav-search-form">
        <div class="gdlr-nav-search-container container"> 
        <form method="get" action="<?php  echo home_url(); ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-search icon-search"></i>
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="style-2" value="">
            <div class="search-text" id="search-text">
                <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" autocomplete="off" data-default="<?php _e("Type keywords..." , "gdlr_translate"); ?>" >
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <?php get_template_part( 'header', 'title' );

    } // page style ?>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
```

please help me how i slove i did not understand

Answer (score 0):

Simply deleting that line and function will remove the fatal error and display the page.

Unfortunately, whatever that function is, is not defined in either a plugin or your functions.php file and will not be rendered.

If you did a find and replace for gdlr_ in your file to rename the function names and class names, you may need to do the same for your functions.php file.

Comment: What errors are you receiving after deleting that line?  You may have additional errors that do not have anything to do with that particular function.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function gdlr_get_image() in /home2/u9447441/public_html/wp-content/themes/clevercourse-v1-27/header.php on line 83`

Comment: Well I can see you are using the Clever Course theme by GoodLayers.
Since you did not rename any of the function names or class names, there is a good chance that you didn't completely upload the theme to your theme folder in wp-contents. Try uploading the theme again, or if you added via the wp-admin backend, manually add it via FTP and check your pages. Simply put, those functions are defined in the functions.php file or in the page.  Since they can not be executed on the page, you are receiving errors. Check to make sure you have a functions.php file in your clevercourse-v1-27 theme folder